# Write someting in a <input> tag in html with selenium c# doesn't work

Tags: c#, html, selenium, automation

I wanted to fill in a input from website with html.

THis how the part of the website (https://account.protonmail.com/signup?language=de) looks like:

```
<div class="flex-item-fluid">
<input autocomplete="username" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" aria-invalid="false" id="username" aria-describedby="id-1" class="w100 inputform-field" value="">
</div>
```

This my c# selenium part:

```
var elem = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='username']")).SendKeys("test");
// I also tried this:
var elem = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='username']")).SendKeys("test");
```

I hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 1):

The element you are looking resides in an `iframe` so first switch the frame.

**xPath for iframe**:

```
//iframe[contains(@src,'Name=username')]
```

Then find the element using below `xPath`,

```
//input[@id='username']
```

**Completed code**:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'Name=username')]")));

var elem = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='username']")).SendKeys("test");
```

Answer (score 1):

The **username field** is in `iframe`

use the below `xpath` to `switch to iframe` first then you can continue with the rest of the code:

```
//iframe[@src]
```

something like this :

```
IWebElement iframe = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//iframe[@src]"));
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(iframe);
```

Also, I see multiple elements for username field. Always remember we should give more precedence to `css_selector` over `xpath`

Username field can be locate with this css:

```
body.color-norm.bg-norm input[id='username']
```

so in code something like this :

```
var elem = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body.color-norm.bg-norm input[id='username']")).SendKeys("test");
var pass = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[id='password']")).SendKeys("password here");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
var elem = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".w100.inputform-field")).SendKeys("")
```

Here we search by class name, not by input name. Good Luck.

if it worked for you. USEFUL